# How do I actually grep 3xa Linux?

Tags: linux, grep

I would like to get only lines that contains 3 x a using grep. So for 
example:

```
zaxczxazxcazxc <- this awqeqweaa  <- this afdlfkasd <- this not aaa <- this
```

Comment: what do you mean 3xa? three `xa` or `3xa`?

Comment: @HowChen I think OP means three occurrences of the letter `a`.

Answer (score 1):

`grep "a.*a.*a" inputfile` will be adequate if it is acceptable to also return lines which contain more than three instances of a i.e. 'aaaa'

if this is not the desired behaviour, then the following is needed:

```
grep "a.*a.*a" inputfile | grep -v 'a.*a.*a.*a'
```

alternatively, the awk command can instead be used as follows:

```
awk -F a 'NF == 4' < inputfile
```

Comment: Your `<` is superfluous - `awk` reads from any named files without redirection.

Comment: I do not wants lines which contain more than three "a"